# EF Data Annotation to Validate Multiple Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I have an example model class `Item`. The following is pseudo-code to describe the model.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public int Total {get; set;}

    public int Accepted {get;set;}

    public int Rejected {get;set;}
}
```

I want to add a data annotation that requires that: (Accepted + Rejected) <= Total. How can I do this using data annotations? My other option to validate this logic in my program, but I thought this seemed like a realistic database constraint that may be possible through data annotations or something similar.

I've looked at annotations such as `GreaterThan` which allow you to compare two properties, but I haven't found anything that works correctly for 3. I'd prefer to avoid writing my own validation too, as it just added extra overhead and hasn't been a successful way to do this in previous attempts.

Let me know if clarification or further code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you have two solution for this. You can write either a custom validation attribute or using `IValidatableObject` in you model class as follows:

**Using `IValidatableObject`:**

```
public partial class Item : IValidatableObject
{
    public int Total {get; set;}

    public int Accepted {get;set;}

    public int Rejected {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
            List<ValidationResult> validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if(Accepted + Rejected > Total)
            {
                validationResults.Add(new ValidationResult("The sum of Accepted and Rejected cannot greater than Total", new[] {""}));
            }

            return validationResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be working in that it is correctly setting `ModelState.IsValid` to `false`. However, the message doesn't appear in the validation summary or anywhere else. Do I have to do something else to show the message on my page or should it be automatic?

Comment: Let me check. It should show in the validation summary.

Comment: Would you please try the updated answer? I have added extra `new[] { "" }` in the `ValidationResult`.

Comment: I have checked that the error message is showing in the Validation Summary even without adding `new[] { "" }` . Would please make sure that your form view containing `@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`

Comment: My mistake. I thought I had set the validation summary to show.. The property isn't intuitive. Thank you for your help, this does exactly what I wanted. And, I can now add other validations like this too.

Comment: Great to see that it has solved your problem! Welcome!